# ¿Porqué no funciona la función alert()?

Tags: javascript

```js
$(function() {
    $('#depnac').on('change', onSelecDepChange);
});

function onSelecDepChange() {
  var id_dep = $(this).val():
  alert(id_dep);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="quitar">
  <div class="col-md-3" id="no">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Departamento de 
          Nacimiento:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control" id="depnac" name="dep_nac_asp">
          @foreach($departamentos as $departamento)
          <option value="{{$departamento->id_dep}}">{{$departamento- 
           >nom_dep}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="no">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Municipio de 
          Nacimiento:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control" id="munnac" name="mun_nac_asp">
          @foreach($municipios as $municipio)
          <option value="{{$municipio->id_mun}}">{{$municipio- 
            >nom_mun}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: El siguiente es mi codigo en HTML

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiando los ":" por un ";".

```
$(function() {
    $('#depnac').on('change', onSelecDepChange);
});

function onSelecDepChange() {
    var id_dep = $(this).val();
    alert(id_dep);
}
```

Saludos y recuerda aceptar respuesta sí te funcionó.

Comment: Se los Cambie y sigue igual al no funciona el alert

Comment: Deberías agregar el error que te arroja en la publicación principal.

Answer (score 1):

Corregí el ":" por ";" y agregue la referencia a jquery

```js
$(function() {
    $('#depnac').on('change', onSelecDepChange);
});

function onSelecDepChange() {
    var id_dep = $(this).val();
    alert(id_dep);
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<select id="depnac">
<option value='1'>prueba</option>
<option value='2'>prueba</option>
</select>
```